# Idiomatic way to say believing you know something but really don't

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiomatic way to describe a situation where someone is overconfident, e.g. they believe they have good knowledge of something but actually they don't.

Background: I am looking for a catchy paper title. The main finding of the paper is that the majority of users of a certain technology characterise themselves as very knowledgeable about it but show very little understanding of it in reality.

Comment: There are many words to describe this depending on the context. . Consider reviewing the [Help Page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) on the proper way to ask a good question...

Comment: However, in a case like this, we usually cite **Dunning-Kruger**...that would make this Q a duplicate many times over. Consider how to make this Q more **on-topic with more details.**

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ Are you suggesting that the poster has overestimated his knowledge of what constitutes a suitable question? :)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I think you are missing the point of the Q. The OP is asking for a definition. 
Yes...that is the actual definition of Dunning-Kruger...if you have a more specific model please edit the OP. r.e. **"(those who) believe they have good knowledge of something but actually they don't."**

Comment: *I kidded myself that I could fly that 747...*

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ Sorry, I was being facetious. I guess it didn't go over so well.

Comment: Please show us how you want to use this expression -- give us a context and a sample sentence with a blank where the expression will go.  Otherwise this is just too vague.

Comment: Clarified the original question :-)

Comment: **Very** closely related: [Is there an adjective for untruthful especially when pretending-to know more than one does about something?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324562/is-there-an-adjective-for-untruthful-especially-when-pretending-to-know-more-t/324690#324690). Answers include bullshitting / dissembling / deceitful / charlatanic / pretentious, but these are SW answers, not idioms (fixed phrases with peculiar grammar and/or word choice).

Comment: [A E's answer at _Describe a fallacious opinion regarding one's own ability to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209496/describe-a-fallacious-opinion-regarding-ones-own-ability)_ has _the Dunning–Kruger effect_, again not an idiom.

Comment: Hello Edwin. So is this a dupe, or is there a possible idiomatic phrase apart from "suffer from Dunning-Kruger effect/cognitive bias"? IOW, does [this post work as a dupe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209496/describe-a-fallacious-opinion-regarding-ones-own-ability?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Comment: @Cascabel The question title does constitute a dupe (idioms of course being a subset of _set phrases_ [a term forcing the broader sense of 'phrase' where I usually use 'string')]). However, the answers below being more idiomatic (generally used), I'd say this is better left open.

Comment: I appreciate your insight and honesty.

Comment: Not worth making into an answer IMO, but for a catchy title relating to doing things without understanding: "wishful tinkerer"/"wishful tinkering" perh.? (Idiomatic in the sense of native playfulness, not existing idioms AFAIK)

Answer (score 3):

You could say these people, despite their claims of know-how, are clearly **out of (their) depth.**

[out of one's depth](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+one%27s+depth)

[The Free Dictionary]

Comment: This is nice...I was also thinking of "in over their head".

Answer (score 1):

The person might be a **fanboy**, i.e. someone who extolls the virtue of a particular technology on the basis of its origin, but does not know much about how it objectively compares with its alternatives, or about how it actually works.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fanboy

Answer (score 0):

***talking out of their ass***

[-online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/talk-out-of-(one%27s)-ass)

...is quite pithy, and catchy.

> Ex. So many people claim they are expert in this area, but most of them are ***talking out of their ass***

That could be a title.

Apart from that, this is a Dunning-Kruger effect and a cognitive bias. So...

***Dunning-Kruger Effect in "XYZ area"***

...sounds more academic

Comment: The OP has been here for almost a week, and nobody has VTCed it. So I answered.